# Is that possible to derive Landau-Fermi liquid theory from microscopic equation?

Tags: condensed-matter, many-body, fermi-liquids

This question arises from reading Wen's book "Quantum Field Theory of Many-body Systems (Oxford 2004)" p204

> To appreciate the brilliance of Landau-Fermi liquid theory, let us look at the
>   many-body Hamiltonian of interacting electrons, namely
>   $$H= \sum_i \left( \frac{ \hbar^2}{2m} \partial^2_{\mathbf{x}_i}+U(\mathbf{x}_i) \right) + \sum_{i<j} \frac{e^2}{|\mathbf{x}_i-\mathbf{x}_j|} $$
>
> It is hopeless for a theorist to solve such a 'nasty' system, not to mention to guess
>   that such a system behaves almost like a free electron system. Certainly, condensed
>   matter physicists did not provide such a bold guess. It is nature itself who hints to
>   us over and over again that metals behave just like a free electron system, despite
>   the strong Coulomb interaction. Even now, I am amazed that so many metals can
>   be described by Landau Fermi liquid theory, and puzzled by the difficulty to find
>   a metal that cannot be described by Landau Fermi liquid theory.

My question is, is there any attempt to derive Landau Fermi liquid theory from the microscopic Hamiltonian given above? Even from numerical side, is that possible to see the emergence of Landau Fermi liquid theory from first-principle calculation, such as density-functional theory?

Comment: There has been some attempts using the renormalization group approach [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/9307009) and [there](http://arxiv.org/pdf/cond-mat/9410013.pdf) for instance.